# Captcha image doesnot change dynamically in drupal 6,if admin is not logged in

Tags: drupal-6, captcha

Iam using Drupal 6.
I want to implement Captcha in static pages. I have used  php  rand() function to create dynamic text from which captcha image will be generated and displayed. This captcha is working fine if admin is logged in. But If admin is not logged in, the captcha text once created won't get changed. I just echo d  the random text generated from rand() function. The value of rand() not getting changed for every refresh. How to get the dynamic text in static pages.

Or is there any alternate way to display captcha with captcha text in static pages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to implement your own captcha ? . you can use drupal captcha module " http://drupal.org/project/captcha " you can configure it to work as image / text / mathematically .

Contact me for further information ..